# Disable diacritics in iOS Messages app?

Tags: ios, internationalization, messages

Some people have reported to me that messages that I send them that originally contained diacritics were garbled, or the diacritics are replaced by boxes/stars etc.

Is there a way to make Messages send all messages without diacritics? (I guess this could be achieved also by making the autocomplete not using diacritics, since I never actually write the diacritics, they are there only because the autocomplete changes some of my words.)

Comment: Have you told these people they should get a new IM client that knows Unicode so they don't get garbled messages? I see this as their problem, not yours. Diacritics can be important and it's their fault they can't see them.

Comment: @CajunLuke: it happens on other iPhones. Actually I investigated a bit now and it seems it's Google Voice's fault...